# Property another UIViewController is null

Tags: ios, properties, uiviewcontroller

I need to access a property of a viewController to pass a color, but this property is nil.

LibraryViewController.h

```
 #import "FinalAlgView.h"

 @interface LibraryViewController : UIViewController{
      FinalAlgView * drawView;
  }

  @property (nonatomic, retain)FinalAlgView * drawView;
```

TableColor.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FinalAlgView.h"
#import "LibraryViewController.h"

 @interface TableColor : UITableViewController {

 FinalAlgView *color;
 LibraryViewController * colorDraw;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain)FinalAlgView *color;

@property (nonatomic, retain)LibraryViewController * colorDraw;

 @end
```

In TableColor.m

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

    self.colorDraw =[[LibraryViewController alloc]init];
 }

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

     self.colorDraw.drawView.lineColor =[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:0.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:0.6];
    NSLog(@"the libraryViewController is %@", self.colorDraw);
    //the libraryViewController is <LibraryViewController: 0x4d03f0>
    NSLog(@"the property is %@", self.colorDraw.drawView);
    //the property is (null)

  }
```

How can I do?

Comment: Are you using storyboards?

Comment: No, I doesn't use storyboards and doesn't use ARC

Comment: Instead of `init` try using `initWithNibName`

Answer (score 0):

try this way...

**FinalAlgView.h**

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIColor *lineColor;
```

**FinalAlgView.m**

```
@synthesize linecolor;
```

**Updated Answer 2**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        coralDraw=[LibrayViewController alloc]init];
        coralDraw.drawView=[[FinalAlgView alloc]init];
      self.coralDraw.drawView.lineColor=[[UIColor alloc]init];

     self.colorDraw.drawView.lineColor =[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:0.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:0.6];
    NSLog(@"the libraryViewController is %@", self.colorDraw);
    //the libraryViewController is <LibraryViewController: 0x4d03f0>
    NSLog(@"the property is %@", self.colorDraw.drawView);
    //the property is (null)

  }
```

Comment: Try to Print Self.ColorDraw.drawView.lineColor

Comment: the color is UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 0.6